# How can I skip the intro videos?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

In Shadow of Mordor, is there a way to skip the intro videos?

They are quite a lot of them and they are unskippable. I started the game and counted about 6 of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found on steamcommunity

[Shadow of Mordor - How to skip intro videos](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=320708706&insideModal=1)

copied from the guide link

> 1. Open an Explorer window by pressing [Windows key] + [E]
> 2. Navigate to your Shadow of Mordor directory in your Steam installation, usually C:\Program Files
>      (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\ShadowOfMordor\
> 3. Navigate further into the game's subdirectory \ShadowOfMordor\game\interface\videos\
> 4. Delete the files I have highlighted in blue in the following screenshot or move them to another directory as a backup. Do not touch
>      any other files.
>
> the highlighted files are
>
> Steam\steamapps\common\ShadowOfMordor\game\interface\videos\intro_cz.vib
>
> Steam\steamapps\common\ShadowOfMordor\game\interface\videos\intro_de.vib
>
> Steam\steamapps\common\ShadowOfMordor\game\interface\videos\intro_fr.vib
>
> Steam\steamapps\common\ShadowOfMordor\game\interface\videos\intro_hu.vib
>
> Steam\steamapps\common\ShadowOfMordor\game\interface\videos\intro_ja.vib
>
> Steam\steamapps\common\ShadowOfMordor\game\interface\videos\intro_mx.vib
>
> Steam\steamapps\common\ShadowOfMordor\game\interface\videos\intro_pl.vib
>
> Steam\steamapps\common\ShadowOfMordor\game\interface\videos\intro_po.vib
>
> Steam\steamapps\common\ShadowOfMordor\game\interface\videos\intro_ru.vib
>
> Steam\steamapps\common\ShadowOfMordor\game\interface\videos\intro_sp.vib
>
> Steam\steamapps\common\ShadowOfMordor\game\interface\videos\intro.vib
>
> Steam\steamapps\common\ShadowOfMordor\game\interface\videos\legal\legaltext.vib
>
> Steam\steamapps\common\ShadowOfMordor\game\interface\videos\legal\legaltext_fr.vib
>
> Steam\steamapps\common\ShadowOfMordor\game\interface\videos\legal\middleware.vib
>
> Steam\steamapps\common\ShadowOfMordor\game\interface\videos\nvidia_splash.vib
>
> Steam\steamapps\common\ShadowOfMordor\game\interface\videos\WBPlay.vib

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Please summarize the steps, because we don't know how long the link works.

Answer (score 3):

**NOTES/DISCLAMERS**

- *Please note, this does delete some files from your computer. If you wish to be able to bring back those intros, please think of cutting
  them into a safe location rather than deleting them entirely. Using
  "Verify Game Cache can also work well*
- *To restore the intros, simply paste the deleted files back into the directory from your backup. Alternatively, run "Verify Game Cache" from Steam*

---

**Here are the steps to skip the intro videos**

1. Open explorer/Windows file manager. Easy way is to press both the **WINDOWS** and **E** key at the same time.
2. Navigate to the directory holding your *Shadow of Mordor* game. Here are the default directories by steam:

   - 32 Bit: *C:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\common\ShadowOfMordor\game\interface\videos*
   - 64 Bit: *C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\ShadowOfMordor\game\interface\videos*
   - **NOTE:** Windows 8 and above all use 64 bit, no 32 bit varients
3. Delete/Cut the following files and folders:

   - **FOLDERS:**

     *Legal*
   - **FILES:**

     *intro.vib*
     *intro_cz.vib*
     *intro_de.vib*
     *intro_fr*
     *intro_hu*
     *Intro_IT*
     *intro_ja.vib*
     *intro_max.vib*
     *intro_pl.vib*
     *intro_po.vib*
     *intro_ru.vib*
     *intro_sp.vib*
     *nvidia_splash.vib*
     *WBPlay.vib*

---

**SOURCE/MORE INFO**
[Link to Steam Community](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=320708706&insideModal=1)

Comment: If somebody could explain the negative down vote, I would be grateful.It will be helpful so I can make better answers for the future. Thanks!

Comment: @_5Pike, could you explain why?

Comment: @BlueTrin, do you know why?

Comment: I didn't vote you down, I voted you up. The only reason I could think of is that someone replied the same thing already ? If you have no better answer than a current answer, please consider editing the answer to improve it rather than adding your own ?

Comment: @BlueTrin I did it before he edited it to input the info. Also, I said how to get the intro back just in case

Comment: Ankham, I didn't vote you down, I explained why someone might have done it. His link was containing the information, you could have edited his answer and add more information ? Usually you don't get voted down for duplicated replies but who knows if someone got annoyed for a random reason.